# Weird disk name after restart in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, 64-bit

Just hit a restart after 24-days-and-something uptime of my Windows 7 x64 based laptop and at boot time saw "Installing device driver software" systray message, then got "You must restart your computer blablabla".

Nothing was saved in event logs but after checking one by one hardware components in "Device Manager" found that my second hard disk is with a different name, not the expected trademark and model:

[image]

Does anybody know what's causing that?

Comment: Is the data on the drive intact? I suggest running a SMART checking utility - there will be one in the disk drive manufacturer's drive utility - and seeing if anything suggests imminent failure. Also, was the system time wrong after the restart? That would suggest that the CMOS battery is exhausted and should be replaced - if some BIOS settings were corrupted that could have led to Windows detecting a new device.

Comment: When did you install MagicISO? It has been a long time since I was interested in such things, but IIRC, these types of drivers used to require "unhealthy" RING level permissions and, potentially depending on the design scheme, hooked onto other drivers to capture and rewrite. This could lead to data corruption (i.e. the reported device name is corrupted)

Comment: The data is intact and the SMART status is perfect. The system time wasn't wrong. And last - MagicISO was installed two years ago and yes, no problems were detected after that

Comment: Can you use a utility like HWinfo to check the drive name? The order of the bytes of the name reported by a drive can be... illogical.

Comment: Drive Model: @ päATËUi01ABD075

Same ...

Comment: @Yorik MagicISO was installed right after the OS one. Writing this comment almost 3 years later means the weird name is still here